# flat elements in arrays with optional, null safe

Tags: java, java-stream

my data structure is

```java
@Data @AllArgsConstructor
class A {
  private B b;
}

@Data @AllArgsConstructor
class B {
  private List<C> cs;
}

@Data @AllArgsConstructor
class C {
  private List<D> ds;
}

@Data @AllArgsConstructor
class D {
  private String value;
}
```

and all member is nullable. so I want to extract all values(in class D) in this data structure with optional for nullsafe.

I imagine

```java
A a = new A(
  new B(List.of(
    new C(List.of(
      new D("a"), new D("b"), new D("c")
    ))
    , new C(List.of(
      new D("d"), new D("e"), new D("f")
    ))
  ))
);


// it will be List.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
var result = Optional.ofNullable(a)
  .map(A::getB)
  .flatMap(.......)   // <-- i don't know this point how to do to flat elements
  .orElse(List.of("empty")) // or 'orThrow`
```

Comment: Just don’t make them nullable. Especially lists should never be nullable, just use an empty list as default value.

Comment: thanks. this data structure is response dto by outside API, so I am not sure fields is not null.

Comment: @rura6502 You mean you receive this data from an external API and some properties come as `null` right? In such a case, you need to instruct your desirialization tool (like Jackson, Gson) to assign default values instead of `null`. That would be the proper solution to the problem. You can provide a sample response message you're getting and specify the tool you're using for parsing. And, by the way, you should be aware that using `Optional` to hide *null-checks* is an abuse `Optional`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var result = Optional.of(a)
        .map(A::getB)
        .map(B::getCs)
        .stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(C::getDs)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(D::getValue)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .toList();
```

Comment: Note that `Optional`’s `map` method does handle `null` by returning an empty `Optional` but `Stream`’s `map` method does not.

Comment: Do you mean, I should make a `filter(Objects::nonNull)` before `Stream`'s `map`?

Comment: If we interpret the OP’s “all member is nullable” as “`getDs` can return `null`” and “`getValue` can return `null`”, you should place a `filter(Objects::nonNull)` *after* the corresponding `map` calls, i.e.  `.map(C::getDs).filter(Objects::nonNull)` and `.map(D::getValue).filter(Objects::nonNull)` Well, if we assume that the lists could also contain `null`, you would also need `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` before the map calls.

Comment: Yes, I make some tests, and indeed, I have to place `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` before each map, I edit my answer, thanks @Holger

Comment: But you don’t need a `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` after `.stream()`. `Optional`’s `.stream()` method will return either, an empty stream or a single non-null element stream.

Answer (score 0):

I would make every DTO responsible for returning not-null value (either `Optional` or empty `List`)

```
@Data @AllArgsConstructor
class C {
  private List<D> ds;
  public List<D> getDs() {
    return ds == null ? Collections.emptyList() : ds;
  }
}

@Data @AllArgsConstructor
class D {
  private String value;
  public Optional<String> getValue() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(value);
  }
}
```